# How to match a version of SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

It is needed to install a new instance of SQL to the existing Windows SQL Server 2008. I have no idea what was used to originally install the existing 4 instances. Is it R5 SP32? Thanks to MS wonderful versioning system nobody knows just by looking at Add/Remove.

The version in Add/Remove is listed as 10.1.2531.0 for all the SQL components (funnily enough, all except the main "MS SQL Server 2008 (64-bit)". When I click "modify" under there it asks where is the original installation dir? I would be happy to know too.

How to find "just the right" installer, in order to avoid version hell, upgrading the existing instances (this is production) and other mess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 10.1.2531.0 is for SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 1.
The following table lists the major releases of SQL Server 2008.

```
Release                         Product version

SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 3  10.00.5500.00
SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 2  10.00.4000.00
SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 1  10.00.2531.00
SQL Server 2008 RTM 10.00.1600.22
```

Check [more details on SQL Server version](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185)

**EDIT:**

You can query database to get these info from database itself like

```
SELECT
 SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS ProductVersion,
 SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel') AS ProductLevel,
 SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS Edition,
 SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') AS EngineEdition;
```

More details on `SERVERPROPERTY`

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I actually found this: http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com.au which is useful for version number. Then also this http://www.sqlserver-training.com/how-to-identify-your-sql-server-version-and-edition-even-if-sql-services-are-not-running/- to use registry keys to see that its Enterprise Edition and to learn that the version listed there is not equal to "Add/Remove" list. Now, MS would spare everybody tons of time if they just listed that in Add/Remove or in start menu somewhere or even when running some "SQL Server Info" on desktop or by running repair in Add/Remove...